# Divide 17 people into two groups, one with 12 and one with 5 people.

Tags: combinatorics

Divide 17 people into two groups, one with 12 and one with 5 people

a) Person a and Person b have to be in different groups

- For this question I think that for every ordered group of 12 there will be and unordered group of 5, so the answer should be 15c12

b) Person a and Person b have to be in the same group

- Here I'm not as sure, I tried drawing it out, is it just answer a divided by two?

Comment: Did you consider to borrow an additional person from a wise old neighbor?

Comment: @Vincent Don't understand your comment. Am I missing something or are you making fun of me?

Comment: It is a very bad joke. I was not making fun of you but of the appearance of the number 17 in your problem. There is a very famous mathematical story about dividing a set of 17 objects (in most versions: camels) into groups, which is then solved by temporary adding an 18th camel. In your problem this won't be of much help.

Comment: @Vincent Oh I see! I will have to look that story up, who doesn't love math and storys!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For a) Suppose that you already put $a$ in group 1 and $b$ in groups 2. Then you need to find the number of ways to divide 15 people to 2 sets, one with 11 people and the other with 4 people. Do the same with $a$ in group $2$ and $b$ in group $1$ and sum up.

For b) Suppose that $a,b$ in group $1$, so you need to find the number of ways to divide 15 people to $2$ sets, one with $10$ people and the other with $5$. Then take $a,b$ in group $2$ and formulate a similar question. Once you solved both sum up the results.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!  So for a): For the first one there are 15 possible other people in the group, for the second it is 14.... all the way down to person number 5. Which means that when person a is in the group with 12, there are $\dfrac{!15}{!4}$ different combinations, and then the same when person b is there, so 2* $\dfrac{!15}{!4}$

Comment: and for b) when person a and b is in the larger group, there are $\dfrac{!15}{!3}$ ways of combining, and when they are in the other, there are $\dfrac{!15}{!5}$, and you can just sum them?

Comment: @AlliHenne In general it looks like you understand the point. But I don't understand why you don't count the number of ways you can choose the people in the second group.

Comment: I was thinking that: If you have all the possible combinations for the large group, all of the possibilities for the smaller one will be included. If every order of the large group happens, should not every order of the smaller one have happend as well?

Comment: @AlliHenne Think about 4 people being divided into sets of 2,2. Then you count $(a,b),(c,d)$ and $(a,b)(d,c)$ only once. I believe the number of ways should always be $n!$ because you basically need all possible rotations all the time. I hope I'm not leading you to a mistake though

Comment: @AlliHenne I mean, n! is the number of ways to sit $n$ people in a line. Now take the first $k$ to be the first group and the last $n-k$ to be the other group.  You get an $n!$ many possibilities for sub-groups of $k$,$n-k$ people and I don't think we count any possibility twice.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it! Does that mean that there are for a) (11! + 4!) ways of organizing the groups when mr a is in group 1 and as many when mr b is in group 1? Your first hint confused me a bit, because in the example with (2,2) you just have 2!+2! for every possible way of organizing. But in you first hint you say we have to count when mr a is in group 1 and then when he is in group 2, and sum. Is not every possible way included in 11!+4!, even when he is in group 2?

Comment: @AlliHenne No I think you are more confused now. The case of 4 people is not $2!+2!$ because $a,b$ are not forced to be in the first group. The case of 4 should be $\frac{4!}{2!}$ for the first set and $2!$ for the second set, so $4!$ in total (you should multiply of course, not sum up because you count all the options for the first and second set).

Comment: @AlliHenne Let's make things simpler. If you understand my answer (and it seems you do) then it is left to solve the following problem: Given $n$ people. In how many ways can you divide those $n$ people into two sets, one with $k$ people and the other with $n-k$. Are we on the same line so far?

Comment: Yes! That's the problem I need to solve. So for $n$ people into two groups we will have $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways for the first group to order themself, and then for the other it should be $(n-k)!$ right?

Comment: @AlliHenne Alright, so now it depends on how you understand the question. I mean, you need to make sure whether you should also count the number of ways to choose people within each group, if you do then your answer is perfect. Otherwise the answer is a little different.

Comment: Oh, do you mean for example in our question, for a) we are locking person a and person b to opposite groups, so we have 15 people who are changing groups! which means that for the groups we have $\dfrac{15!}{(15-12)!}$*$(15-12)!$

Comment: @AlliHenne We should consider deleting some of our comments. Anyway yes you are right (note that you also count the number of ways you can rotate the people in each group).

Comment: Yes we should haha! Thank you so much for your help, sorry for being a bit slow, just started with combinatorics. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Hello again sir! I'm not sure I still understand your resoning. I discussed with some friends the reasoning! And according to this, if we have 3 people and are to divide them into 2 groups, one of 2 and one of 1, then we should have $\dfrac{3!}{1!}$ * $1$ which is 3!. But in fact we only have 3 different ways, not 3! which is 6. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AlliHenne This is what I tried to explain before. It looks like you don't need to count the number of ways to choose people withing each group.  Let me explain, your friend says that all the options are $\{1,2\},\{3\}$ and $\{1,3\},\{2\}$ and $\{2,3\},\{3\}$. But that means he counts $\{1,2\},\{3\}$ and $\{2,1\},\{3\}$ as one. If you want to go with your friend's approach (which might be right it you need to ask for clarification) then the number of ways to divide $n$ people to a group of $k$ people and a group of $n-k$ people is $\binom{n}{k}$.